# How to disable pivot grid ordering in devexpress?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am new in devexpress. I have data list to bind pivot grid. And I order my data list from SQL command. But as default pivot grid reoreder my data list to show.

I don't desire to reordered my list. Is it possible to ignore default ordering of pivot grid or some columns?

Comment: Please write a more descriptive title; the current title is effectively useless for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Source:** [How to disable default ordering of pivot grid ?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T311381)

> The cause of this behavior is that he pivot has it's own data engine
>   and has to sort data. Using the provided solution, you can sort field
>   values in a custom way, for example, using the order from the data
>   source.

Go through DevExpress thread - [Disable Sorting in PivotGrid RowArea](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q391060) to more detailed information about the required functionality.

You can use the [ASPxPivotGrid.CustomFieldSort](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxPivotGridASPxPivotGrid_CustomFieldSorttopic) event to sort data manually.
It is necessary to sort data manually by handling the ASPxPivotGrid.CustomFieldSort event. Do your calculation of sorting and grouping at this event. Below, I have posted a code snippet, demonstrating how to disable sorting:

```
private void pivotGridControl1_CustomFieldSort(object sender, PivotGridCustomFieldSortEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = e.ListSourceRowIndex1.CompareTo(e.ListSourceRowIndex2);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

References:
[ASPxPivotGrid remove custom sort/order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329382/aspxpivotgrid-remove-custom-sort-order)

Comment: Thanks for your helps Niranjan. Your solution help me to solve my problem.